# Windmill in an open circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, power

I have a question for which I did not find any relevant answer on the web.

What happens to the kinetic energy of a rotating windmill if  the windmill is not connected to any power line, that is if the windmill is in an open circuit ?

I would think that in this case, all kinetic energy is transform into heat. Is this the reason why sometimes the price of electric energy gets negative ?

Is the resistance to rotation of the windmill stronger when the electric power is used ?

I suppose that this will apply to any electric generator ?

Thanks

Comment: They [feather](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_pitch#Wind_turbines) the blades. Otherwise, with no electrical load the only resistance to motion is friction, and there is a need to stop the blades turning to prevent a 'runaway' which will overheat the bearings or damage the blades.

Answer (score 0):

If the windmill generator is connected to an electrical load, the generator shaft becomes hard to turn, signaling the fact that there is a net power flow being pulled out of the wind and delivered to the electrical load.

If the windmill generator is not connected to any load, then spinning the generator will create no current flow and require no work to spin. This means the windmill blades themselves will experience no resistance to turning and the windmill will speed up until the friction losses in the bearings and in the blades equals the energy being extracted from the wind. This is usually enough to start the bearings on fire and overstress the hub assembly to which the blades are attached, causing them to break loose from the hub and fly to pieces. There are dramatic videos on youtube illustrating this process in real life.